# Update x rows from a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I've this table:

Table `___Units`

```
|--------|------------|
| UNI_Id | UNI_Status |
|--------|------------|
|      1 |     active |
|      2 |     active |
|      3 |     active |
|      4 |     active |
|      5 |     active |
|      6 |     active |
|--------|------------|
```

How can I update the status to `inactive` for the two last created rows (so the highest UNI_Id) only if the current status is `active`.

This is what I tried:

```
UPDATE ___Units SET UNI_Status='inactive' WHERE (
    SELECT * FROM ___Units ORDER BY UNI_Id DESC LIMIT 2
) sub
ORDER BY UNI_Id ASC
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join with a subquery that returns the two highest IDs.

```
UPDATE ___Units AS u1
JOIN (
    SELECT UNI_Id
    FROM ___Units
    ORDER BY UNI_Id DESC
    LIMIT 2) AS u2 ON u1.UNI_Id = u2.UNI_Id
SET u1.UNI_Status = 'inactive'
WHERE u1.UNI_Status = 'active'
```